# How should I convert an objects attribute of type list containing one object to an attribute of type object using Jackson?

Tags: java, jackson

I have a POJO like the following:

```
public class Foo {
   private String name;
   private List<Bar> bars;
   // getters and setters
}
```

It is possible that `bars` could be a null reference, a list containing 0 elements, a list containing 1 element, or a list containing more than 1 element.

The serialization of this object will look like this when converted to JSON:

```
{
   "name: "foo",
   "bars: [{}, {}]
}
```

In the case that the list contains 1 element, I have a requirement that the *type* of `bars` be "condensed" to a single object upon serialization. The JSON representation should look something like this:

```
{
   "name": "foo",
   "bars": {}
}
```

How can I achieve this using Jackson?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of digging through the docs I found [WRITE_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations/2.8.4/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonFormat.Feature.html#WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED)

> Override for SerializationFeature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED which will force serialization of single-element arrays and Collections as that single element and excluding array wrapper.

The implementation is pretty straightforward and requires the addition of the following annotation to the Object getting serialized: `@JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED)`

```
public class Foo {
   private String name;
   @JsonFormat(with = JsonFormat.Feature.WRITE_SINGLE_ELEM_ARRAYS_UNWRAPPED)
   private List<Bar> bars;
   // getters and setters
}
```

With this annotation added to `Foo`, the JSON output is:

```
{
   "name": "foo",
   "bars": {}
}
```